# Can I have a custom Model argument for @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring MVC automatically wires the Model or ModelMap arguments on `@RequestMapping` methods, but can it do this for a subclass of ModelMap? If so, where do I create the subclass instance?

I think Spring MVC treats an un-annotated argument as a command object and will fill its field from the request. I really don't want this happening, so I am a bit afraid to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, all you need is @ModelAttribute annotation.  For instance, I have a method declared like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**/contractComplete.do",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public static void handleContractComplete(
        @ModelAttribute(ParamConstants.CONTRACT) ContractCommand command,
        BindingResult result,
        HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) throws IOException
```

---

Or perhaps this will help:
At the declaration of my controller, I have

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(ParamConstants.CONTRACT)
```

And the result is that it uses the same command object that I put into the model when I launched the page.  This object, I suspect, could be anything that extends (or implements) the class of the argument.

Comment: I am already using `@ModelAttribute` and `@SessionAttributes`, but since I have gone through the trouble of putting the 10 or so model attribute into a data holder class, I don't really want to use these annotations anymore. I just want my Model sub-class to be the model.

Comment: After doing loads of searching, I think this is the best work-around for now.